# Azure Storage Gui

Tags: azure-storage

I'm trying to create a GUI based script so that i can easily select same as web interface selecting from List View . Trying to acheive this using powershell .  I would like to create azure resource group directly using the location i selected . The same approach would be for creating Azure Storage account as well . Let me know if there are any resources / pointing websites where i can check on sample script which has already implemented such option for Azure . 
I tried hard coding all the values that i need as a part of power shell script under parameters but would want to use it in a GUI . 
Any pointers would be greatly helpful . I tried using Windows forms 
New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label  that has been throwing errors .

I tried below approach but the form loads but fails to use the parameters i have selected :

```
Add-Type -Assembly Name System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -Assembly Name System.Drawing
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Select a Resource Group'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
$form.Start Position = 'Center Screen'
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = 'OK'
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)
$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)
$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label.Text = 'Please select a Resource Group:'
$form.Controls.Add($label)
$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$listBox.Height = 80
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('West Europe')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('East US')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('West US')
$form.Controls.Add($listBox)
$form.Topmost = $true
$result = $form.ShowDialog()
if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult   ]::OK)
{
 New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Location 
 $resourceGroupLocation
 }
```

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: No Ivan i did retry but still running in to issues with unknown exception resource not found error . Below code works independently when executed when trying to add few more lines it throws an error . Can you add in your full sample code that worked /?

Comment: I added the full code which is used to create a resource group, and you can run the code in powershell ISE if you like. Please let me know if you have any issues. And if it works, please help mark it as an answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

```
 Add-Type -AssemblyName system.drawing
 $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
 $form.Text ='Select a Resource Group'
 $form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
 $form.StartPosition ='CenterScreen'
 $OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
 $OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
 $OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
 $OKButton.Text = 'OK'
 $OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
 $form.AcceptButton = $OKButton 
 $form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

 $CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
 $CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,120)
 $CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
 $CancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
 $CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
 $form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
 $form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

 $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
 $label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
 $label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
 $label.Text ='Please select a Resource group'
 $form.Controls.Add($label)

 $listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
 $listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
 $listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
 $listBox.Height=80

 #get all the available location
 $mylocations = Get-AzureRmLocation | select DisplayName
 foreach($location in $mylocations){[void]$listBox.Items.Add($location.displayname)}
 $form.Controls.Add($listBox)
 $form.TopMost = $true
 $result = $form.ShowDialog()

 $selectedLocation = $listBox.SelectedItem
 Write-Output $selectedLocation

 if($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
 {
    New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name "your_resource_group_name" -Location $selectedLocation
 }
```

---

If you use powershell, you just need make some changes in your code.

1.use `Get-AzureRmLocation | select DisplayName` to get all the locations, then add all of the locations to the listbox:

```
$mylocations = Get-AzureRmLocation | select DisplayName

foreach($location in $mylocations){[void]$listBox.Items.Add($location.displayname)}
```

2.after select the location in the dialog, then use `$listBox.SelectedItem` to get the selected location.

```
$selectedLocation = $listBox.SelectedItem

#use the selected location to create resource group
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Location $selectedLocation
```

Please let me know if any more issues.

Comment: Hi Ivan that worked fine when i tried to use for locations , i'm trying to add a subscriptions and resource groups as well to the drop down list and then add a place holder for input of " Storage Account " , i have tried using 

~~~~
$mysubscriptions = Get-AzureRmSubscription | select DisplayName
~~~~
also wanted to pass " your_resource_group_name " as a text instead of hardcoding i read it as Read-Host using Input Text , how do i pass these values to the single selection

Comment: @Viswanath, do you mind posting a new issue for this? And let me know the link, thank you :).

Comment: posted new issue in link to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56124581/extending-azure-storage-gui